# Is is possible to select a DOM element using a querySelector with a concatenated Variable?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select a DOM element using a concatenated Variable?

*Here is the basic code I have tried:*

```
var customColor ="";
var customID = "#customPort-1-colorStyle";

$(".colorStyle input:radio").change(function() { 
customColor = document.querySelector(customID + '-colorStyle' + ' ' +  input:checked);
alert(customColor.value);
});
```

*Here is an example CodePen (not working):*
https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/VVqgqo?editors=1010

Any thoughts or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: I do not see an element with an id of `customPort-1-colorStyle-colorStyle`

Comment: You also have a typo that the last part of your selector (`input:checked`) is not a literal string.

Comment: if you're looking for the value of the selected radio you can use `this.value`

Comment: Also, please avoid asking question that could be answered with a simple yes or no.  State what you want to happen, and explain what issues you have in achieving it.  Because the answer to your question as it currently is, is simply "yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The reason your pen isn't working is because you're using `-` instead of `.` to indicate a class and your `input: checked` should be enclosed in quotes.

With that, your js can then become:

```
var customColor ="";
var customID = "#customPort-1-colorStyle";

$(".colorStyle input:radio").change(function() {
  customColor = document.querySelector(customID + '.colorStyle input:checked');
  alert(customColor.value);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQXJxv

Comment: Assuming it's not a typo and they didn't mean to add the -colorStyle twice to the selector.  Given it's an id, there's really no reason to include the class in the selector

Answer (score 1):

The event will only trigger on the radio that is actually changed

No need to query the dom inside the change handler for that same element.

Just do

```
$(customID  + ' :radio').change(function()
     alert(this.value)
})
```